# IComparable.CompareTo correct implementation considering inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The question is related to entity framework and in memory sort.

Reading this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=netframework-4.7.2
I should throw an exception if classes are not of the same type (or, looking example, the compared class is not an instance of the comparable class).
I'm using `GetType().IsInstanceOfType(obj))` to determine if I should throw `InvalidArgumentException` as required by API specification.

I have 2 classes

```
public class MyClass : IComparable
{
    // ...
}

public class MyClassProxy : MyClass
{
    // This class rappresent an EF proxy
    // ...
}
```

Applying API specification, `MyClass.CompareTo(MyClassProxy)` should work fine while `MyClassProxy.CompareTo(MyClass)` should not work.

The question is, in this case should I respect exactly the API definition or should I partially release the API constraint about types and do not throw the exeption if the class is a proxy of the comparable class?

If I release the constraint how is the right way to check types compatibility?

Comment: "Applying API specification, MyClass.CompareTo(MyClassProxy) should work fine " - it doesn't sound like it to me. "obj is not the same type as this instance." is not true in this case, so it makes sense to throw ArgumentException, IMO. I'd use `GetType() != obj.GetType()` here.

Comment: @JonSkeet, the example in the API specification works with derived classes. I think that the word `is` in API specification has to be indended as c# `is` keyword.

Comment: I'd argue that's a bug in the implementation. Note that later on, it says: "The parameter, obj, must be the same type as the class or value type that implements this interface; otherwise, an ArgumentException is thrown." The word "is" isn't even in that sentence. Having an asymmetric implementation is highly confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you would have the same question if `MyClass` would implement `IComparable<MyClass>` instead or (or maybe as well as) `IComparable`

Let's do the same question with a less abstract example.

Suppose we have a class `Animal`. Every Animal has a `NumberOfLegs`. We'd like to order Animals by this number of legs, so we implement `IComparable<Animal>`.

Suppose we also have a class Human, derived from `Animal` (although some will question that). Every `Human` has a `Name`, and we'd like to order `Humans` by name, so we implement `IComparable<Human>`

Similarly we have a `Spider`, which of course is an eight-legged `Animal`:

```
class Animal : IComparable<Animal> {...}
class Spider : Animal, IComparable<Spider> {...}
class Human : Animal, IComparable<Human> {...}
```

The following will be easy to answer: what are the values of x and y?

```
Animal spider = new Spider();
Animal bill = new Human("William Shakespeare");
int x = spider.CompareTo(bill);  // +1 A spider has more legs than bill
int y = bill.CompareTo(spider);  // -1: bill has less legs than Spider
```

Let's do it Again: what is the value of z?

```
Spider spider = new Spider();
Human bill = new Human("William Shakespeare");
int z = bill.CompareTo(spider); // ???
```

**What would you like to be the meaning of this**? Class `Human` does not implement `IComparable<Spider>`, and not all Spiders have a name. So all we can do is to compare by number of legs, which is exactly what will happen.

If you really wanted a special handling when comparing humans and spiders (for instance on fearfactor), you should let Human implement `IComparable<Spider>` (or vice versa).

Now that you know exactly what you would do when you would implement `IComparable<Human>`, `IComparable<Animal>`, etc. I think you'll know what to do if you'll also implement `IComparable`

**One final remark**: Only implement `IComparable<...>` for a class if your comparison method is typical of objects of the class. This is, if everyone would say that your method would be the natural way of ordering these kind of objects.

It is not the natural way to order Animals by number of legs. Therefore readers wouldn't know instinctively what the following would do:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> myAnimals = ...
var result = myAnimals.OrderBy(animal => animal);
```

Animal should not  have implemented IComparable like this. We should create a special Comparer class that implements `IComparer<Animal>` on number of legs:

```
class AnimalLegCountCompare: IComparer<Animal> {...}
```

The following would be less confusing for readers:

```
ICompared<Animal> legCountComparer = new AnimalLegCountComparer();
var result = myAnimals
   .OrderBy(animal=>animal, legCountComparer);
```

Comment: Thanks for you very precise answer. The issue in this case is a little bit different. Following your example, I have an Animal class that implements IComparable<Animal>. Entity Framework creates a proxy class over my Animal class that is totally outside of my control (and transparent to my application). Lets call it AnimalProxy. Now I have a collection that contains Animal and AnimalProxy. Usually I should follow your suggestion but in this case I think (but I'm not sure) that the proxy creation and the proxy use should be totally hidden to the user (the programmer).

Comment: So, why not create a special comparer clas that implement `IComparer<AnimalProxy>`? In that class you can compare any way you want. The only restriction is that you have to make sure that if A is smaller than B then B is larger than A. This is comparable to all StringComparer classes. Every StringComparer compares strings differently. You can even make one Comparer class that can compare Humans and Spiders if you want.

Comment: The main problem is that third party components uses IComparable. The second issue is that is quite hard to create `IComparable<AnimalProxy>` because is dynamically generated by Entity Framework so I should dynamically implement `IComparable<AnimalProxy>`